# HTML begin form is showing empty form as output and not supporting html helpers inside

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

html helpers are not working inside the begin form,

however they are working fine, if i place them outside the begin form..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    Html.Label("", "Username", new { id = "userInp", @class="labs"});
    Html.TextBox("userbox", "", new { placeholder = "Enter Username" });
}
```

**Results in:**

[image]

**ordinary `<input>` tag is working but html helpers are not wokring inside the begin form body.**

Comment: Typo: put a `@` before `Html`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/7iYxU5

Comment: it worked, thanks but i don't understand the reason, why it worked?

Comment: It's how you tell razor "this method returns an HTML string, actually print it" rather than it going into the void.